# django form to upload file returns error as form not valid

Tags: forms, validation, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am developing an app in Django.
My users are allowed to save data by compiling a form like this

> Tool:
>
> acronym:
>
> definition:

defined by the following function, in forms.py:

```
class tool_form(forms.ModelForm):
                
    class Meta:
        model=tool
        fields=["Tool", "Acronym", "Definition"]
```

That saves the data into a model like this:

```
class tool(models.Model):

    Tool = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    Acronym = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    Definition = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The view function allowing this, is:

```
def add_tool(request):
  
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = tool_form(request.POST or None) 
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
            messages.success(request, ("Submit succeed!"))
            return redirect('adding_tools')
            
        else:
            
            messages.error(request, ('ERROR: submit failed'))
            return render(request, 'adding_tools.html', {})
    
    else:   
        return render(request, 'adding_tools.html', {})
```

Now I want my users to be able to copile many times of the same form, all at once.
In order to achieve this, I am allowing my users to upload a file copiled with the data to insert.
So I am allowing my users to download a template xlsx file with colums with given name

> Column 1 name (cell A1): Tool
>
> Column 2 name (cell B1): acronym
>
> Column 3 name (cell C1): definition

To compile it, inserting many records, and then to upload it back.
So I want my code to save this data into the same model declared before (tool)
I am trying to achieve this by:

in template add_tool_sheet.html:

```
   <form class="container" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="file-upload-wrapper" id="input-file-now">

            <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Select file to upload.</small>                  
            <input type="file"  name="uploaded_file" id="input-file-now" data-max-file-size="5M" class="file-upload">
            
            <br><br>
            
            <div class="form-group">                
                 <input name="Date" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="date_to_turn_into_toda">              
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

in forms.py:

```
class tool_file_form(forms.ModelForm):
                
    class Meta:
        model=tool_file
        fields=["Tool_file", "Date"]
```

In models.py

```
class tool_file(models.Model):

    Tool_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_sheets/', blank=False, null=False)
    Date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now().date() )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Date', 'Tool_file']

    def clean(self):
        if not (self.Tool_file or self.Date):
            raise ValidationError("something went wrong")
        

    def __str__(self):    
           
        return  "%s ----- [%s]"  %  (self.Tool_file, self.Date)
```

in views.py:

```
def add_tool_sheet(request):

    
    if request.method=='POST': 

        form = tool_file_form(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()            
            
            messages.success(request, ("upload succeeded"))
            return redirect('add_tool_sheet')

        else:
            
            messages.error(request, ('ERROR n1'))
            return render(request, 'add_tool_sheet.html', {})
    
    
    else:   
        return render(request, 'add_tool_sheet.html', {})
```

When I try to add new objects in the model tool_file from admin section, it works.

But when I try to add new objects from the user interface (template add_tool_sheet.html), it returns

> ERROR n1

as message, and my console returns

> GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7381

Why?

**Please note:**

The upload from admin section works, the upload from user interface does not.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong with your template but if you want your users to bulk import data from an excel file, shouldn't you consider using an import tool such as https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?
This would allow your users to directly add new entries in the tool models, and would make the upload of the file itself in a separate model no longer needed.

Comment: I have already implemented it for the admin section, I thought that tool was only to import data from admin section.  I found no indication in using that from a template... Could you please point me an expample of this use of import-export?

Comment: did you check the link? There is a fairly comprehensive example https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

In template I put

```
name="uploaded_file"
```

but in order to match with the information in forms.py and model.py, it has to be:

```
name="Tool_file"
```

Now it works!

Comment: also, I recommend this tutorial to accomplish this task https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rr1-UTFCuH4